# error while executing "apache services"

Tags: apache, windows-7, installation

i am trying to install apache version 2.2.16, on my windows 7 machine. the apache is installed correctly. but when i try to run the service, i get a error message saying, "The requested operation has failed"...
i tried all the methods, i.e disable antivirus, skype, 
but still the same result.

Comment: what do you see in the errorlog ? let us know what it says. so that we can zero down the issue.

Comment: [Sat Jul 31 22:20:32 2010] [warn] pid file C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

Answer (score 0):

Are you runnin IIS on the same machine? By default, they will try to bind to the same port 80), and if IIS is running on bootup, then Apache will not be able to start. Try disabling IIS on startup, or else change the port that one or the other uses.

Comment: I have the same problem. In fact, at one point I was able to access the website I had set up (locally) in IIS via Apache, with the 'It works!' message not showing up for localhost:// but for that site www.localsite.com, is there any way to disable IIS while using Apache or explicitly give a different port?